# Google Apps Script Utilities.parseCsv() change decimal and thousand separator

Tags: csv, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am new to GAS and I am struggling badly with the problem that I have. (I haven't found a similar question on the site that would have solved my problem, therefore I am asking a new one)

**Goal**: Import CSV from Google Drive into Google Sheets
**Problem**:
Currencies in the csv file are "1,000.57" --> US format
Currency format that I need "1.000,57" --> European format

Currently with the `Utilities.parseCsv()` the formats just gets messed up and the currencies are plain wrong.

**Question**: Is there a way to change "," to "." and "." to "," during the parse? If so, will there be further problems since the delimiter for the csv is "," as well.

I already found some code snippets in the web (not my code: props to spreadsheet.dev) and tried to change the following, but it does not seem to work:

```
//Imports a CSV file in Google Drive into the Google Sheet
function importCSVFromDrive() {
  var fileName = promptUserForInput("Please enter the name of the CSV file to import from Google Drive:");
  var files = findFilesInDrive(fileName);
  if(files.length === 0) {
    displayToastAlert("No files with name \"" + fileName + "\" were found in Google Drive.");
    return;
  } else if(files.length > 1) {
    displayToastAlert("Multiple files with name " + fileName +" were found. This program does not support picking the right file yet.");
    return;
  }
  var file = files[0];
  var csvString = file.getBlob().getDataAsString()
  var escapedString = csvString.replace(",",".")
                                .replace(".",",");
  var contents = Utilities.parseCsv(escapedString);
  var sheetName = writeDataToSheet(contents);
  displayToastAlert("The CSV file was successfully imported into " + sheetName + ".");
}

//Prompts the user for input and returns their response
function promptUserForInput(promptText) {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var prompt = ui.prompt(promptText);
  var response = prompt.getResponseText();
  return response;
}

//Returns files in Google Drive that have a certain name.
function findFilesInDrive(filename) {
  var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
  var result = [];
  while(files.hasNext())
    result.push(files.next());
  return result;
}

//Inserts a new sheet and writes a 2D array of data in it
function writeDataToSheet(data) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  sheet = ss.insertSheet();
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  return sheet.getName();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is actually the delimiter of your csv file ? Is it a semicolon ? may be you can take this code https://gist.github.com/IranthaJ/0754b24ee8aa588dbd5403b1ed500405#file-csvtospreadsheet-gs

Comment: @MikeSteelson thanks for the quick answer Mike. My CSV file actually has comma as seperator. I tried the code you provided, but unfortunately it resulted in the following error :"Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property getFolderById on object DriveApp.
importCSV"

Comment: Can you give us a sample of your csv file ? and where is it located ?

Comment: If you separator is comma `,` then any data inside cells that contains comma should be in quotes `"` (in a propper CSV). In this case you can find and replace any commas inside quoted texts. It's not a big deal. Though if your data contains quotes inside quotes... So a solution heavily depends on your data. There is not a common universal solution.

Comment: `var escapedString = csvString.replace(",",".").replace(".",",");` it's too funny. A common mistake.You would get commas everywhere (if you managed to replace all, not only one letter). In such cases you need three steps: replace `,` --> `_` then replace `.` --> `,` and then replace `_` --> `.`.

Comment: @Mike Steelson: Will upload a copy later (have to clean some sensitive data prior to share them). In general: will download the csv from the web --> put them into my Google drive and upload it from there into my google sheet.

Comment: @Yuri Khristich thanks for your explanation Yuri. In the comment to the other answer I posted a CSV with sample data. Unfortunately, the data that contains the comma is not in quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So sample of your CSV data is here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ASevYOWtu8YL6YA4w-UqDuNXAS0RfaJF/view?usp=sharing

It looks for me like just plain CSV data:

```
Trades,Header,DataDiscriminator,Asset Category,Currency,Symbol,Date/Time,Quantity,T.Price
Trades,Data,Order,Stocks,USD,ALGN,"2021-06-28,10:50:27",3,627.17,621.52,-1881.51,-1,1882.51,0,-16.95,O
Trades,Data,Order,Stocks,USD,AMAT,"2021-06-29,09:38:53",14,142.15,141.92,-1990.1,-1,1991.1,0,-3.22,O
Trades,Data,Order,Stocks,USD,APH,"2021-07-02,09:30:01",30,69.438,69.95,-2083.14,-1,2084.14,0,15.36,O
```

I see no "european" formatted numbers out there.

I believe it can be parsed correctly into this:

| Trades | Header | DataDiscriminator | Asset Category | Currency | Symbol | Date/Time | Quantity | T.Price |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Trades | Data | Order | Stocks | USD | ALGN | "2021-06-28,10:50:27" | 3 | 627.17 | 621.52 | -1881.51 | -1 | 1882.51 | 0 | -16.95 | O |
| Trades | Data | Order | Stocks | USD | AMAT | "2021-06-29,09:38:53" | 14 | 142.15 | 141.92 | -1990.1 | -1 | 1991.1 | 0 | -3.22 | O |
| Trades | Data | Order | Stocks | USD | APH | "2021-07-02,09:30:01" | 30 | 69.438 | 69.95 | -2083.14 | -1 | 2084.14 | 0 | 15.36 | O |

I haven't tried to do it with `Utilities.parseCsv()`, I wrote my own little csv-parser, just to be sure that the task is doable and my assumptions are correct:

```
var s = `Trades,Header,DataDiscriminator,Asset Category,Currency,Symbol,Date/Time,Quantity,T.Price
Trades,Data,Order,Stocks,USD,ALGN,"2021-06-28,10:50:27",3,627.17,621.52,-1881.51,-1,1882.51,0,-16.95,O
Trades,Data,Order,Stocks,USD,AMAT,"2021-06-29,09:38:53",14,142.15,141.92,-1990.1,-1,1991.1,0,-3.22,O
Trades,Data,Order,Stocks,USD,APH,"2021-07-02,09:30:01",30,69.438,69.95,-2083.14,-1,2084.14,0,15.36,O`;

// replace ',' with '_' inside quotes
s.match(/("[^,]+),(.+")/g).forEach(t=>s=s.split(t).join(t.replace(/,/g,'_')));

// replace ',' with '\t', replace '_' with ',' and split string into 2-d array
var array = s.replace(/,/g,"\t").replace(/_/g,',').split('\n').map(x => x.split('\t'));

console.table(array);
```

Output:

```
┌─────────┬──────────┬──────────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────────┬────────────┬──────────┬─────────────────────────┬────────────┬───────────┬──────────┬────────────┬──────┬───────────┬─────┬──────────┬─────┐
│ (index) │    0     │    1     │          2          │        3         │     4      │    5     │            6            │     7      │     8     │    9     │     10     │  11  │    12     │ 13  │    14    │ 15  │
├─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼─────────────────────┼──────────────────┼────────────┼──────────┼─────────────────────────┼────────────┼───────────┼──────────┼────────────┼──────┼───────────┼─────┼──────────┼─────┤
│    0    │ 'Trades' │ 'Header' │ 'DataDiscriminator' │ 'Asset Category' │ 'Currency' │ 'Symbol' │       'Date/Time'       │ 'Quantity' │ 'T.Price' │          │            │      │           │     │          │     │
│    1    │ 'Trades' │  'Data'  │       'Order'       │     'Stocks'     │   'USD'    │  'ALGN'  │ '"2021-06-28,10:50:27"' │    '3'     │ '627.17'  │ '621.52' │ '-1881.51' │ '-1' │ '1882.51' │ '0' │ '-16.95' │ 'O' │
│    2    │ 'Trades' │  'Data'  │       'Order'       │     'Stocks'     │   'USD'    │  'AMAT'  │ '"2021-06-29,09:38:53"' │    '14'    │ '142.15'  │ '141.92' │ '-1990.1'  │ '-1' │ '1991.1'  │ '0' │ '-3.22'  │ 'O' │
│    3    │ 'Trades' │  'Data'  │       'Order'       │     'Stocks'     │   'USD'    │  'APH'   │ '"2021-07-02,09:30:01"' │    '30'    │ '69.438'  │ '69.95'  │ '-2083.14' │ '-1' │ '2084.14' │ '0' │ '15.36'  │ 'O' │
└─────────┴──────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────────┴────────────┴──────────┴─────────────────────────┴────────────┴───────────┴──────────┴────────────┴──────┴───────────┴─────┴──────────┴─────┘
```

If you add `range.setValues(array)` instead of `console.table(array)` you probably will get a propper table in your sheet.

**Update**

To replace `123.45` --> `123,45` in the array you need to add one line at the end:

```
array = array.map(row => row.map(cell => cell.replace(/(\d)\.(\d)/g, '$1,$2')));
```

Comment: Hi Yuri, thanks a lot!. You are correct, the data in the csv is not european, but US. The goal would be to have european. So with your own written csv-parser, you were able to accomplish the task. Nice! The only change in the output that I need would be : '-1881,51'  instead of '-1881.51' (changing the "." to "," ).

Comment: So do you need any help?

Comment: Yes please. 1) With the change in the output from '-1881.51' to '-1881,51'. 2) How your final code would look like. Sorry, I am just strugelling. Thank you

Comment: I just updated my answer. You need to add one line only to modify a content of the array. Do you have a problem to put array on your sheet?

Comment: I've made a full version of the script based on your sample. You can use it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1CpG6rnrbzP9VCBw5GwVlW4hphIJpRIiP8goJrIsbPYE/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: thanks a lot for your work Yuri! that solved the issue!

Answer (score 2):

`Utilities.parseCsv()` is a hot mess.  I recommend you not to use it.  Instead, try the [Advanced Google Service - Drive V2](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)

You will need to add Drive under Services.

Here is the code snippet you will need:

```
function insertFromCsv(fileName) {
  var blob = DriveApp.getFilesByName(fileName).next().getBlob();
  var tempFile = Drive.Files.insert({title: "tempSheet"}, blob, {
      convert: true
  });
  var tempSsId = tempFile.getId();
  var tempSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(tempSsId).getSheets()[0];
  var newSheet = tempSheet.copyTo(SpreadsheetApp.getActive());
  DriveApp.getFileById(tempSsId).setTrashed(true);
  return newSheet.getName();
}
```

and change `importCSVFromDrive` as follows:

```
function importCSVFromDrive() {
  var fileName = promptUserForInput("Please enter the name of the CSV file to import from Google Drive:");
  var files = findFilesInDrive(fileName);
  if(files.length === 0) {
    displayToastAlert("No files with name \"" + fileName + "\" were found in Google Drive.");
    return;
  } else if(files.length > 1) {
    displayToastAlert("Multiple files with name " + fileName +" were found. This program does not support picking the right file yet.");
    return;
  }
  var file = files[0];
  // var csvString = file.getBlob().getDataAsString()
  // var escapedString = csvString.replace(",",".")
  //                               .replace(".",",");
  // var contents = Utilities.parseCsv(escapedString);
  // var sheetName = writeDataToSheet(contents);
  var fileName = file.getName();
  var sheetName = insertFromCsv(fileName);

  displayToastAlert("The CSV file was successfully imported into " + sheetName + ".");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that sounds promising. I followed your instructions: added Drive in Version V2 under Services and run your code snippet: Unfortunately, the following error prompted: "Exception: Invalid argument: name" Do I have to change anything else?

Comment: Just a guess. Perhaps you need to define `fileName` before you call the function. Probably it should be `var fileName = "Test_data_2.csv"`

Comment: I don't know why or where you get that message.  I edited my answer above to add a return of the sheet name and to show you how to call my function in your code.

Comment: @AlsoRan: thanks for your updated version. It is running now nicely. But in the output, the parsing still has to done right? Because the output looks excatly like the input in the csv now.

Comment: @Bierbaron1920: A csv file should not have separators in numbers unless the application that generated the file thinks it is a text field.  What is the format of your number column after the import?  and what is the locale of the google sheet?

Answer (score 0):

I create a csv file and test here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/148muW2MhTBwXfppFhO85gQv6GRduvyb5OMHeS68VWH4/edit?usp=sharing

```
function importCsvFromId() {
  var id = '1yc04iLf20k6oVlwSMpWm-xythMPKJoBO';
  var csv = DriveApp.getFileById(id).getBlob().getDataAsString();
  var csvData = Utilities.parseCsv(csv);
  var f = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet()
  f.getRange(1, 1, csvData.length, csvData[0].length).setValues(csvData);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort Mike, I just checked the data and basically all data with comma is without quotes. I guess it will be tough then. I uploaded a csv with sample data here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ASevYOWtu8YL6YA4w-UqDuNXAS0RfaJF/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I store the data in my drive ... https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yc04iLf20k6oVlwSMpWm-xythMPKJoBO/view?usp=sharing, and update the script by chaging the ID ; no problem !